# Reimage PC with SCCM TS from PXE and rename with same PC name

Tags: sccm

I am trying to find a way to re-image some PCs in SCCM with a task sequence and have the PC have the same name as it did prior to imaging. Is it possible to store the current PC name from the PXE boot via Powershell or something use it afterimaging and prior to joining the domain to rename the computer? I have tried to find info on this but keep coming up short. If anyone has links to info  or a solution please point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled here. Do you use a system where the name of the client in your sccm console is not the same as the computername? Or are you deleting that record? Because if you just assign a TS to a client and image it it will by default have the name it has in the console so it will always keep it's old name

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's me that was a bit puzzled. I am new to SCCM and I'm trying it in a test environment in hopes we can implement this at work. I did not know it would keep the same name. I ran the TS and imaged the PC and it retained its computer name. Thank again for the reply.

Comment: no problem. great that it worked out exactly the way you wanted. this will probably not always be the case with sccm but no worries with the help of this site and lot's of great sccm blogs/forums you will probably find a solution to most of your needs.